# Extensions of proteins in SARS-CoV-2 variants

Tags: genetics, mutations, coronavirus

What lineages of the coronavirus SARS-CoV-2 occurring in the wild show some extensions, i.e., mutations of the stop codons to codons encoding amino acids (mutations to another stop codon don't count here).

By chance I found that the pango lineage B.[1.1.318](https://outbreak.info/compare-lineages?pango=Lambda&pango=Mu&pango=Delta&pango=Alpha&pango=Beta&pango=Gamma&pango=AZ.1&pango=AZ.2&pango=AZ.4&pango=B.1.1.318&pango=AZ.2.1&pango=AZ.3&pango=AZ.6&pango=AZ.5&gene=ORF1a&gene=ORF1b&gene=S&gene=ORF3a&gene=M&gene=E&gene=ORF6&gene=ORF7a&gene=ORF7b&gene=ORF10&gene=N&gene=ORF8&threshold=75&dark=false) has an extension of the accessory protein encoded by ORF7b.

Are there more such cases, and what lineages are affected?

Comment: Due to a 15nt deletion around the ORF7b stop codon B.1.1.318 has a merge of ORF7b and ORF8 giving ORF8: MKF 1:3 MIELSLIDFYLCFLAFLLFLVLIMLIIFWFSLELQDHNETCHAY